# Why useEffect does not behave like what i expect?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering Why this isn't an infinite loop?
I set the state inside of the useEffect hook and that should re-render the component and useEffect will be ran again and again and agian...
why this isn't what i expected?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then((r) => {
        console.log("Checking...");
        setData(r.data[0]);
      });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: It will and does run repeatedly?  The reason it does not throw a maximum update exceeded error is because state is being updated within a promise.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect also accepts an array of dependencies i.e., useEffect will get executed when any values inside the array changes. So, if you want useEffect to be called whenever `data` changes, do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then((r) => {
        console.log("Hello world");
        setData(r.data[0]);
      });
  }, [data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **useEffect** hook needs a second parameter, the dependency array.
When this dependency array is empty it will have the same behavior as the **componentDidMount**

If you add some dependencies to your array as **data** this useEffect will be executed every time that the data state changes.

So, if you want to fetch the data when the component loads you must do something like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").then((r) => {
        console.log("Hello world");
        setData(r.data[0]);
      });
  }, []);
```